# iText PdfDictionary encoding issues?

Tags: java, pdf, character-encoding, itext

When I create a PDF file, I attach some info to it with this code to make it readable to my program:

```
        PdfDictionary dictionary = new PdfDictionary();

        PdfObject object;
        PdfName index;

        ArrayList<String> content = getCompactData(document);

        for (int i = 0; i < content.size(); i++)
        {
            object = new PdfString(content.get(i));
            index =  new PdfName(Integer.toString(i+1));

            dictionary.put(index, object);
        }

        writer.getExtraCatalog().putAll(dictionary);
```

When I'm opening the program, I use this code to extract the data:

```
                PdfDictionary dictionary = reader.getCatalog();

                PdfName index;
                PdfObject line;

                ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();

                for (int i = 1; i < dictionary.size()-2; i++)
                {
                    index = new PdfName(Integer.toString(i));
                    line = dictionary.getAsString(index);
                    data.add(line.toString());
                }
```

That all works great except for one little detail. Characters such as čšđćž are not passing to the process properly for some reason. Once I try to extract data, my program gets confuset and can't recognize the letters.

Several notes:

1. My workspace encoding is UTF-8
2. When working with my program i can enter those letter with no problems, they'll be displayed properly.
3. I use custom .ttf (truetype) font which I know supports these characters
4. I tried printing out contents of the catalog after the last line of the save-code I provided, everything was printed out properly.
5. I also tried printing out the contents of catalog a line before the first one in the open-code, characters were not displayed.

So I have no idea where could it all go wrong.
Do you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You incorrectly use the `PdfString` class. Instead of

```
object = new PdfString(content.get(i));
```

use

```
object = new PdfString(content.get(i), PdfObject.TEXT_UNICODE);
```

and instead of

```
data.add(line.toString());
```

use

```
data.add(line.toUnicodeString());
```

Some background information:

The constructor you used attempts to use the **PDFDocEncoding**:

```
/**
 * Constructs a <CODE>PdfString</CODE>-object containing a string in the
 * standard encoding <CODE>TEXT_PDFDOCENCODING</CODE>.
 *
 * @param value    the content of the string
 */
public PdfString(String value)
```

Your characters `čšđćž` are not present in that encoding.

The other constructor allow you to choose the **UTF-16BE** encoding instead:

```
/**
 * Constructs a <CODE>PdfString</CODE>-object containing a string in the
 * specified encoding.
 *
 * @param value    the content of the string
 * @param encoding an encoding
 */
public PdfString(String value, String encoding)
```

For character extraction `toString` only returns an internal representation while `toUnicodeString` cares about the encoding:

```
/**
 * Returns the Unicode <CODE>String</CODE> value of this
 * <CODE>PdfString</CODE>-object.
 *
 * @return A <CODE>String</CODE>
 */
public String toUnicodeString()
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked!


P.S. You might also want to write to change `line` from `PdfObject` to `PdfString`